# Система поощрения - медальки, бейджики

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм

Как лучше всего организовать систему поощрения для пользователей (медальки, знаки, бейджики)? В какой структуре БД лучше ее делать, и где лучше эти поощрения хранить.

*К примеру, для игр:*

- медалька X с цифрой "1" за первую победу
- медалька X с цифрой "2" за 10-ую победу
- медалька Y с цифрой "1" за первый проигрыш

т.е. медалька с обозначением уровня. В этом случае, где хранить тип медальки (X, Y, ...) и за что их давать, и где хранить за какое значение давать N-ый уровень (подозреваю что тут прописывать жестко в коде придется)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример автоматических медалей:

БД с юзерами. БД с медальками.

Т.е.:

```
users
+---------+---
| user_id | ..
|---------|---
| 10      | ..
+---------+---

medals
+----------+--------------+---
| medal_id | min_messages | ..
|----------|--------------+---
| 1        | 10           | ..
+----------+--------------+---
| 2        | 100          | ..
+----------+--------------+---
| 3        | 1000         | ..
+----------+--------------+---
```

Медали даются за сообщения. Чем больше сообщений, тем больше медалей.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM medals AS m, users AS u
WHERE u.messages > m.min_messages
ORDER BY m.orderVal ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b994/10

Comment: супер. И можно будет немного улучшить таблицу, добавив тип медальки, например так:

    SELECT * FROM medals AS m, users AS u
    WHERE (u.messages > m.min_messages AND m.types = 1) 
      OR (u.photoCount > m.min_messages AND m.types = 2)
    ORDER BY m.orderVal, m.types ASC

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/707f2/4

Comment: @IVsevolod ну это вроде как стандартная работа вознаграждений на форумах. Я бы разграничил медали и поощрения. Т.е. допустим сравнение с хешкодом: медали даются за кол-во очков уважения автоматически, а вот плюсы и минусы ставятся участниками.

Answer (score 2):

проще всего будет одна таблица со стобцом типа:

```
Ник юзера    Медаль 1   Медаль 2    Медаль 3
```

А строка в таком виде:

```
username        Y          N           N
```

Где, Y - это наличие медали. Если надо хранить уровень храните его вместо Y, если он больше 0 то медаль есть, если равно нулю то медали нету.

Comment: ага, особенно весело если типов медалек over 500.

Comment: появление новой медали будет приводить к обновлению таблицы?

Answer (score 2):

Обычная же штука:

Таблицы:

```
acheivs: id,name,desc,condition(если можно формализовать правила получения),once(один ли раз можно такую получать)
user_acheivs: user_id,acheiv_id
```

после события после которого можно получить ачивку(в вашем примере - победа/проигрыш) проверяем conditions и once, вставляем  значение во вторую таблицу.

Comment: спасибо :) направление мышления получил ) буду пробовать :)

Comment: ну да, там конечно можно еще вести лог, за что получил ачивку и прочее, такие структуры увеличивают абстрактность данных (что иногда запутывает).

Answer (score 1):

*Как лучше всего организовать систему поощрения для пользователей (медальки, знаки, бейджики)?*

Если вас интересует разработка оной системы поощрения, а не её реализация, т.е., вопросы за какую деятельность следует награждать участников и как, и если идёт речь не об игре, а о применении подобного рода методов в неигоровой ситуации, то я очень рекомендую новый (бета) сайт [Gamification](http://gamification.stackexchange.com/) в системе StackExchange. Вопросы эти крайне нетривиальны и ответы на них сильно зависят от ваших целей и целевой аудитории: мужчины и женщины реагируют по-разному, представители разных культур реагируют по-разному, и т.д.

Comment: спасибо. Полезная информация :)